# SQL query for fetching friend list

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with SQL query.

I have two tables. One is users and other one is userfriends

```
users table:
aid email                    firstname 
1   example@mail.com         example
2   example2@mail.com        example2
3   example3@mail.com        example3
4   example4@mail.com        example4

userfriends tables:
reqid     email                    friendemail               status 
1         example1@mail.com        example2@mail.com            1       (example1 is frnds with example2)
2         example2@mail.com        example4@mail.com            2       (example2 request pending)
3         example3@mail.com        example1@mail.com            1       (example1 is frnds with example3)
4         example4@mail.com        example1@mail.com            1       (example1 is frnds with example4)
```

So when status is 2 the add request is pending and at  status 1 they are friends. What i want is that i want to retrieve the complete friendlist for user example1. I want to pull out names from users table for corresponding output from previous query to display as friendlist.

Comment: you really should use id pointers to the `users` table in your `userfriends` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you guys are missing the fact that the searched for email could be in either column:

```
select u.firstname
from userfriends f, users u where 
u.email='email@domain.com' and f.status=1 and
(u.email = f.email and f.friendsemail='email@domain.com')
or
(u.email = f.friendsemail and f.email='email@domain.com')
```

Comment: You are right. Above queries just return wherever friendsemail is myemail.
I tried your query and it works except that it return me my own name only and not friends name.

Comment: Unknown column 'u.friendemail' in 'where clause'

Comment: oops, should be `f.` not `u.`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It's 5 AM here and this is really blowing up my mind. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct friendemail
from userfriends f
inner join users u on u.email = f.email
where f.status = 1
and u.firstname = 'example'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both tables:

```
SELECT users.firstname 
    FROM userfriends UF 
    JOIN users U ON (U.email=UF.friendemail)
WHERE UF.email='your user'
```